# Hibernate and Sleep suddenly stopped working [Windows 7]

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, hibernate

System is Windows 7 x64 SP1

Right now the system cannot enter either sleep or hibernation modes.

When I select either Sleep or Hibernate, system just switches to the login screen which shows an option to enter my account, which is still logged in.
Nothing else happens. System reboot does not help.

Previously I used hybrid sleep for years, never had anything like that happening.
No system settings were changed before the problem appeared.
Changing any settings in Power Options did not solve the problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this, why this is happening?

Currently if I try to hibernate with "shutdown -h", I get this:

```
The requested system device cannot be found.(15299)
```

---

Things I checked which were listed as solutions to a similar problem:
- activating a recovery partition - I never had one
- enabling diskpart automount - did nothing
- marking Windows partition as active, after it was unmarked by GRUB - my Windows partition is already marked as active
- checking if the hibernation file is created - it is

Comment: [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/244364/windows-7-can-sleep-but-cannot-hibernate) might help in part. You could also run [powercfg -energy](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/) and post the result file.

Comment: Install the latest graphics driver available.

Comment: Looking at that post doesn't seem like it will be any help since the problem the user had seems to be completely different, and I never had any recovery volumes so the solution doesn't apply in any case.
On the other hand powercfg -energy found a bunch of errors, I'll need to check to log file.

Comment: I have a bunch of "USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend" errors, however these are related to the devices not entering suspend state, not the system itself. No hardware changes were made before my problem with suspend/hibernate appeared.